# How do I make an Xpath element visible using Selenium?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

An unhandled exception of type `OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException` occurred in `WebDriver.dll`

Additional information: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression `//*[@id='hdtb-msb']/div[1]/div[4]/a)` because of the following error:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string `'//*[@id='hdtb-msb']/div[1]/div[4]/a)'` is not a valid XPath expression.

I have tried finding the element through Class as well -- didn't seem to be working. Then remembered that it could be a time issue. After reading several articles/posts, I am not sure what else to try.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace Webdemo2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "http://gooogle.com";
        var searchbox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
        searchbox.SendKeys("Pluralsight");

        //adding timeout 
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));

        var images = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='hdtb-msb']/div[1]/div[4]/a)"));
        images.Click(); 
              }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Please add the html

Comment: HTML:

<a class="q qs" href="/search?q=Pluralsight&amp;biw=1037&amp;bih=751&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiVm-_225nRAhUs4IMKHS__BiMQ_AUICCgD">Images</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your xpath expression:

```
/a)
```

I think you need to take that closing parenthesis out of the expression.

Comment: Ah, you were right about the closing parenthesis! It was able to be move pass that but the next line threw System.InvalidOperationException. I did a little reading. Could the problem be out of focus?

Comment: And I do have the latest ChromeDriver.

Comment: Cool, mark it as the right answer so other people know. Have you got the full exception/relevant code for the next error?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='hdtb-msb']/div[1]/div[4]/a"}

Comment: The comment box is saying the code is too long to be added as a comment.

Comment: Hmm ok, you can add it to the original question, though it sounds like either the xpath is incorrect, or as you suggested the element is not visible to be selected.